# How to simultaneously check for the existence of a response and of its subnode in JSON?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the noob question.

I have a JSON response that will sometimes return different responses, and I need to check the contents of a sub-node of one type of the possible responses. Right now I have a nested condition, is there any way to further simplify this?

```
if("FooResponse" in rsp){
  if(rsp.FooResponse.code === 0){
    // do something;
  }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to simultaneously check for the existence of a node and its subnode without having to do a two-level conditional check?

Comment: See [Logical Operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
if(rsp.FooResponse && rsp.FooResponse.code === 0){
```

Comment: really? If `rsp.FooResponse` is undefined, wouldn't that `.code` throw an error?

Comment: Right, which is why the two level check is needed in the first place.

Comment: @Blaise No, it woudln't throw an error : the second test is only executed if the first one passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do using

```
if(!!rsp.FooResponse && !!rsp.FooResponse.code && rsp.FooResponse.code === 0)
```